# How to serialize a class with a complex property using XML serialization in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, xml-serialization

I want to serialize a class. In this class there's a property of type Class1 that in turn has its own properties.

```
public abstract class ComponentBase
{
    [ToSerialize] //An attribute defined my me, indicating whether or not to serialize this property.
    public ComponentArgs Parameters { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentArgs
{
    public string WorkingPath { get; set; }
    public IList<Language> Languages { get; set; }
    public string ComponentOutputPath { get; set; }
}
```

The information serialized must be put into a `Dictionary<string,string>`, such as

```
ComponentSettings[str_Name] = str_Value;
```

The method used in reading this value is Reflection

```
// pinfo: Property Info got via Type.GetProperties();
componentSettings.Add(pinfo.Name, pinfo.GetValue((object)this, null).ToString());
```

The information after serialization is:

```
<Parameters>MS.STBIntl.Pippin.Framework.ComponentArgs</Parameters>
```

instead of the value of `ComponentArgs.WorkingPath`.

The solution I thought of is to append to the following line an if judgement:

```
componentSettings.Add(pinfo.Name, pinfo.GetValue((object)this, null).ToString());

if(pinfo is ComponentArgs)
    componentSettings.Add(pinfo.Name, pinfo.GetValue(
        (ComponentArgs)this, null).WorkingPath+"\n"+
        LanguageList+"\n"+ //Language list is a concatinated string of all elements in the list.
        (ComponentArgs)this, null).ComponentOutputPath+"\n"+
    );
```

When deserializing, add a judgement of whether the value contains more than 2 "\n", if so, extract each value from the string.

But this way seems clumsy and much more like an workaround. I wonder if there's any more professional way of doing it? My reviewer is very particular and he won't accept such a solution. If you know a way, could you please share it with me? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to use inbuilt serialization.

The simplest and oldest is the `[Serializable]` attribute that tells .NET to serialize the members.

You can also use the WCF `[DataContract]` attribute to serialize stuff.

There is also the `IXMLSerializable` interface which allows you to implement custom XML readers and writers for you classes.

The bottom line is, there is no need to roll your own - it has been done.